# React-Saga giving Type-Error - isBatchingLegacy

Tags: next.js, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, module-federationnextjs-mfutils

I am working on a module federation architecture which consists of

1. State management app written in react 17 which uses redux-saga for async calls to firebase
2. an app-shell which has imported the state management as a remote, this is also written in React 17.

I am trying to migrate this app-shell to Next-13 and since it requires React 18, i updated the state management and all its dependencies (redux, react-redux, redux-saga) to the latest version. The micro-frontend setup is working properly but when i dispatch an action from the app-shell an error is being thrown in redux-saga,

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isBatchingLegacy')`

I have downgraded to React 17 but that doesn't also seem to work. React is being shared in the module federation setup. Does anyone know what the solution to this is.